# Android Room DB not finding an existing column that contains list of another entity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

my DB is set up well, but now I am shifting from:

```
var note_items: MutableList<String>
```

to:

```
var note_items: MutableList<NoteItem>
```

and I get an error that note_items column is not recognized... 
even when adding @columnInfo:

```
@Parcelize
@Entity(tableName = "note_table")
data class Note(var title: String
                , @ColumnInfo(name = "note_items") var note_items: MutableList<NoteItem>
                , @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) var id: Long = 0

) : Parcelable {

}

@Parcelize
@Entity
data class NoteItem(@PrimaryKey /*@ColumnInfo(name = "note_items")*/ var text: String,
var description: String  ): Parcelable
```

only if I add the @ColumnInfo to a var within NoteItem, does the app recognize and run but I wish to retrieve the ENTIRE object and not just a single var within it.

```
@Query("SELECT note_items FROM note_table WHERE id = :noteId")
fun getNoteItems(noteId: Long): LiveData<MutableList<NoteItem>>
```

adding my Converters class just in case:

```
class Converters {

    companion object {

        @TypeConverter
        @JvmStatic
        fun listToJson(value: MutableList<NoteItem>): String {
            return Gson().toJson(value)
        }

        @TypeConverter
        @JvmStatic
        fun jsonToList(value: String?): MutableList<NoteItem> {
            val gson = Gson()
            val type= object : TypeToken<MutableList<NoteItem>?>() {}.type
            return gson.fromJson(value, type)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to add the `TypeConverters` to your `database`

```
@TypeConverters(Converters::class)
abstract class AppDatabse : RoomDatabase() {

    //
}
```

And also in your `note_items` field of `entity` if needed

```
@TypeConverters(Converters::class)
@ColumnInfo(name = "note_items") 
var note_items: MutableList<NoteItem>
```

Also update your `Converters` like below to keep it simple:

```
object Converters {
    @TypeConverter
    @JvmStatic
    fun listToJson(value: MutableList<NoteItem>): String {
        return Gson().toJson(value)
    }

    @TypeConverter
    @JvmStatic
    fun jsonToList(value: String?): MutableList<NoteItem> {
        val gson = Gson()
        val type= object : TypeToken<MutableList<NoteItem>?>() {}.type
        return gson.fromJson(value, type)
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response (and simplifying Converters). I've got all these basics in the code so still seeking an answer.

Comment: I don't understand why do you face problem if you do all basics, It's working fine in my case. `note_items` is recognized without *ColumnInfo*

Comment: wow thanks for trying it out! can you check if there are more diffs from my code?

@TypeConverters(Converters::class)
I added only at top of the RoomDatabase() class, as it doesnt go well in the entity class.